# ¿Cómo crear subcarpetas dentro de directorio res/layout?

Tags: android, gradle

### Problema

Con el propósito de llevar un orden (ya que tengo muchos archivos `xml`) quisiera saber como crear subcarpetas; dentro de la carpeta `res` esta la carpeta `layout` y dentro de esta quiero crear subcarpetas:

```
layout
-- producto
   -- detalle_producto.xml
   -- agregar_producto.xml
-- servicio
  -- detalle_servicio.xml
  -- agregar_servicio.xml
```

### Intentos

Investigando encontré un ejemplo que lo realiza por medio de  [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
        [
                'src/main/res/layouts/layouts_category2',
                'src/main/res/layouts',
                'src/main/res'
        ]
    }
}
```

Con varias modificaciones  lo he dejando así, (nótese que cambie `res` por `resources` ya que con `res` me producía error)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.srcDirs =
        [
                'src/main/res/layout/producto',
                'src/main/res/layout/servicio',
                'src/main/res/layout',
                'src/main/res'
        ]
    }
}
```

El problema de esta solución parcial es que en los archivos `xml` al mover a la subcarpeta me marca en rojo la etiqueta.

### Datos adicionales

Uso Android Studio 1.5

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te sale? y ¿cuál es el código que estás usando?

Comment: El error que me sale es que las etiquetas contenedoras de mis archivos `xml` estan en rojo despues de mover a la subcarpeta.

Comment: Debes dar más detalle de tu problema porque por el momento la pregunta está a punto de ser cerrada.

Answer (score 9):

Por lo que entiendo usted quiere tener directorios dentro de `res/layout`, hasta ahi lo entiendo pero lo que no entiendo es cunado dice que esta teniendo problemas y menciona algo que le muestra en color rojo, de todas forma le voy a mostrar algunas manera que puede usar para su propocito:

---

## 1 Esta es basada mas o menos en lo que usted comenta:

Tomare como base esta estructura que usted proporciona:

```
layout
-- producto
   -- detalle_producto.xml
   -- agregar_producto.xml
-- servicio
  -- detalle_servicio.xml
  -- agregar_servicio.xml
```

Comentar que esta forma se puede hacer de muchas maneras:

Yo lo que haria de usar esta manera seria crear lo siguiente en el fichero `build.gradle.`

**Primero** (añadirlos como puedes ver debajo)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 //..
    sourceSets {
        main {
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layout/producto',
                            'src/main/res/layout/servicio',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Segundo A** (crear los directorios "procduto y servicio" o bien desde un explorador o desde la shell, dentro del directorio ../res/layout de su proyecto.

O

**Segundo B** *"Quizas aqui es donde usted esta teniendo problemas, porque lo que se documenta puede ser algo confuso y es:"*

> El Android project view define su propia estructura y no puede
>   modificarse.

Asi que aunque las cree, quizas no las pueda ver, lo que hacemos es cambiarnos a Project structure view, le adjunto imagen:

Cambiamos la vista a Project structure view clicando en `Project` donde pone `Android`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora navegamos hasta el directorio `res/layout` y con el raton creamos los directorios que queremos, los que añadimos al `gradle` file.

En este punto si despues de actualizas/syncronizas no puede verlos ni despues de hacer un `Build` > `Clean` revise los pasos anteriores.

Y para los `xml` correspondiente pues los crea como habitualmente o los copia dentro de los nuevos directorios.

---

---

## 2 Le dejare informacion de como usar un plugins que yo uso quizas le guste mas para este tipo de tareas.

```
Plugins datos:

nombre   : Android File Grouping Plugin v1.1
autor    : dmytrodanylyk
lisencia : MIT
rep      : https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin
```

Partimos de un gradle file sin modicar, "me refiero a que si usa el mismo proyecto puede borrar lo que se añadio anteriormente", para evitar errores o ver como funciona mas facilmente:

Le echamos una visita al GitHub a esta direccion ->
https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin/releases

Descargamos la ultima en este momento es la 1.1,

si no quiere estar con el src y eso pues bajamos el siguiente:

```
Downloads

Android.File.Grouping.v1.1.1.zip
```

depues de descargarlo (no lo descomprima jaja):

Hacemos: `File` >> `Settings` y dentro de settings click plugins (se le mostrar algo como esto)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pulsamos en `install plugins from disk...` se abre un explorador y seleccionamos el fichero que descargamos antes:

Reiniciamos.

Ahora creamos los `xml` algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  producto_detalle
  producto_agregar
  servicio_detalle
  servicio_agregar
```

Note que se a cambiado el orden poniendo lo que tienen en comun estos xml al principio.

Obteniendo algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora sobre el directorio layout hacemos boton derecho y podra ver una nueva etiqueta con el nombre de `Group` clicamos sobre el:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambiamos la vista a Project structure view clicando en `Project` donde pone `Android`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Navegamos y podemos ver algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede cambiar el filtro que usa el plugins para *simular los directorios, puede crear los suyos propios como puede ver si entra en `File` >> `Settings` > `Other Settings` > `Android Folding`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si selecciona Hiden Folding Prefix lo vera de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Notas:**

*simula -> el plugins no crea ningun directorio solo lo simula.

- No mueve los ficheros
- Ni crea los directorios

La primera forma como puede ver si que los crea.

Notas:
si se crea una parte usando la primera parte de la respuesta y luego se hace un grupo sobre el mismo directorio se suele ocultar lo que se creo con la primera parte, usted puede hacer y deshacer un grupo de igual manera que lo creo pues si hay un grupo creado solo le aparece deshacer el grupo.

P.D: si tiene cuenta de GitHub y le gusta esta herramienta puede darle una `Star` al desarrollador.

https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/folding-plugin

Comment: Excelente explicación instalando el plugin de la segunda forma y de alguna manera funciona pero solo en la vista Project, sabes si hay que hacer alguna configuración adicional para poder verlo en la vista Android que es la que uso por el tema de que me muestra lo necesario.

Comment: si se fija debajo del apartado segundo b, le deje lo siguiente -> El Android project view define su propia estructura y no puede modificarse. Me imagino que no se puede, pero no estoy del todo seguro si existe alguna modificacion para ello pero diria casi seguro que hasta hoy la vista android en "res" no deja de esa manera Saludos

Answer (score 1):

> Dentro de la carpeta res esta la carpeta layout y dentro de esta
>   quiero crear subcarpetas.

El propósito de agregar carpetas dentro de `res/layout` no es destinado para organizar tus archivos, **es específicamente para agregar recursos que puedan ser desplegados en dispositivos de diferentes tamaños y densidades**, estos definidos por [calificadores](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Los recursos pueden ser organizados de acuerdo a su [calificador](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) por tamaño y densidad, lo cual podemos ver en la documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si deseas realizar un tipo de "organización" de layouts esto puede realizarse comunmente con prefijos en tus archivos, o de otra forma **mediante configuracón en el archivo `build.gradle`**, es importante hacer notar que estos nombres deben ser definidos en letras minusculas :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
        [
                'src/main/res/layouts/layouts_productos',
                'src/main/res/layouts/layouts_servicios',
                'src/main/res/layouts',
                'src/main/res'
        ]
    }
}
```

Esto mismo se puede realizar para otro tipo de recursos como son `/drawable`, `/mipmap`, `/values`,  `/anim`, `/color`, `/raw`, `/xml`, etc., los cuales son [admitidos dentro del directorio de recursos `/res`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

**Editando....**