# Android Studio - Barra oculta el código

Tags: android-studio, xml, ide

¿Alguien sabe por qué me aparece esta barra tan molesta?

[image: Barra esconde el código, el puntero está al final de la sentencia]

De repente aparece, pongo el puntero al final de la línea y la tapa, me ha pasado unas cuantas veces, en esta ocasión cuando compilé mi proyecto. Quiero saber si se debe a alguna configuración que le moví, **¿Alguna solución que no sea reiniciar el IDE?** Sólo he tocado los temas, regresé al Darcula (creo que es el predeterminado oscuro).

Android Studio está actualizado.[image: Android Studio última versión, actualizado]

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Puede o debe ser que has modificado el tema del ide de Android Studio. Puedes personalizarlo o ponerlo por defecto en File / Settings / Editor / Color Scheme y como tienes el problema desde el XML, pues busca en ese apartado.

Comment: No sé si haya sido el motivo, pero después de regresar toda la configuración de Android Studio a su estado original, recordé que instalé el plugin mostrado en la primera respuesta de la siguiente pregunta. Anexo el enlace --> (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2155/c%C3%B3mo-crear-subcarpetas-dentro-de-directorio-res-layout).